# What happens when a JDBC database number exceeds Java's int size during ResultSet.getInt?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, int, precision

I am search for the documentation which specifies what happens if I call [getInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29) on a JDBC result set for a column containing a value which does not fit into an integer. The documentation for [getInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29) does not specify this. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: It might pretty well be undefined by standard (but you have to read the spec to know that). In any case, if you know a column can contain a bigger number, then you should not use `getInt()`. This can be hard with some databases that do not have a strict type system like sqlite though. So after all you may need to look at your JDBC driver sources.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases getInt() for a Number which is too large will overflow.  I suggest you test this yourself as the behaviour is likely to be specific to the JDBC driver you are using.